# whereis returns different path to which

Tags: command-line, bash

I use the command `whereis rm`

```
$ whereis rm
/bin/rm
```

Then I try `which rm`

```
$ which rm
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/rm
```

The results are different... so which `rm` will be called when I run a command like `rm readme`?

Comment: `type rm` is likely to be more reliable than either - since it will show any path that has been cached by the shell

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?  A default installation of Ubuntu will have the command `rm` contained only in the `/bin` folder in the path.  Everything I am finding for that `which` command is that it comes from `brew` installing the `coreutils` on a Mac.

Comment: Are you using Mac OSX? @user10726006

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/40304/959374) by [Denilson Sá Maia](https://superuser.com/users/10758/denilson-s%c3%a1-maia) may be useful:

> `which` searches your user-specific PATH (which may include some of the locations whereis searches, and may not include others - it might also include some places that `whereis` doesn't search if you'd added to your PATH).
>
> `whereis` searches the standard *nix locations for a specified command.
>
> ```
> $  whatis which
> which                 (1)  - shows the full path of (shell) commands
>
> $  whatis whereis
> whereis              (1)  - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command
> ```
>
> Basically, `whereis` searches for "possibly useful" files, while `which` only searches for executables.
>
> I rarely use `whereis`. On the other hand, `which` is very useful, specially in scripts. `which` is the answer for the following question: *Where does this command come from?*
>
> ```
> $  which ls
> /bin/ls
>
> $  whereis ls
> ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1p/ls.1p.bz2 /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.bz2
> ```

Answer (score 3):

According to manual of `which`:

> which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  commands  in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell. It does this by searching the PATH for executable files matching the names of the  arguments. It does not canonicalize path names.

According to manual of `whereis`:

> whereis locates the binary, source and manual files for  the  specified command  names.  The supplied names are first stripped of leading pathname components and any (single) trailing extension of  the  form  .ext (for  example:  .c)  Prefixes  of s.  resulting from use of source code control are also dealt with.   whereis  then  attempts  to  locate  the desired  program in the standard Linux places, and in the places specified by $PATH and $MANPATH.

So clearly there is a very thin of difference among them. `which` results include path of executable file while `whereis` results in binaries and documentation.

For example, consider java:

- `which` results in just one path, i.e. path of java executable file

  ```
  /usr/bin/java
  ```
- `whereis` results in about paths, i.e. path of java binary, source and manual

  ```
  java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
  ```